# Time series prediction is not working at the first step of test data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series

I am doing some time series prediction. I am using the historical data and temperature to predict the energy for the next three days. The way I create the training data is same as LSTM, i.e I'm using a sliding window through the time series data. Overall, the prediction is not bad. But, at the first hours of the day the prediction is not good as the other hours in the day. I provide a photo of the predition and the real value. I also show the time which I talk about it.

Maybe my question is so dumb. But, do you have any idea how I can improve this error at the first hour of the day? Any other features can play a role here to solve this?[image]

Comment: Can you give some code to check the architecture?